# Virus from adult websites?

Tags: iphone, virus

I go to my safari and it says I have viruses from adult websites, I'm guilty of that yes. But it then shows its checking my android in one tab and another says my iPhone has a virus. Is this true? Or is it a s scam!?

Comment: Since when Safari has the ability to detect whether it's infected or not? Maybe the page that tells you that you have a virus is a scam itself? What's the URL in the address bar? How does the message look like? Please attach some screenshots, then we can proceed with getting rid of any kind of malware / virus etc.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly a SCAM.

Safari has nothing to do with that, that is a website with the info and it was opened by the adult website.

Viruses usually do not announce themselves to you.

Try opening new tab and search for Google. No virus there!

Just delete the website in question, you do not have a virus.

Comment: Issue will be that you can't delete the page as it blocks Safari completely